# JavaScript / SAPUI5 how do i append to and export a file to a specified location?

Tags: javascript, file, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 (Javascript) App that reads oData from an API. That oData needs to be accessed from another system (ABAP), so one of the options is to append the data to a file and save it to a specific location.

What is the best method for doing so?

Comment: where is this SAPUI5 app is hosted or you are planning to host ?

Comment: It's hosted on SAP cloud platform. But it could also be hosted on our on Premise Fiori server.

Answer (score 0):

- Fiori app hosted on SAP Cloud Platform:
  You can do this with

  > SAP Cloud Connector

  and I there are many blogs which explain the complete connection.
  This can work as a reverse proxy with your On-Premise system to establish a connection with the SAP Cloud platform. [How to setup SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Connector](https://www.sap.com/india/developer/tutorials/hcp-cloud-connector-setup.html) and
- Fiori app hosted on another On-Premise frontend server:

  This can be done with

  > SAP Netweaver Gateway

and you can have an RFC connection established to connect from frontend server to the Backend OData Service. [A reference blog on OData Service using Gateway](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/26/step-by-step-guide-to-build-an-odata-service-based-on-rfcs-part-1/)

Also, I recommend you to read about Fiori Architecture which will give a clear idea of what are you looking for. You can find multiple blogs for this as well.